# How to use the Service Connection to insert into Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure, powershell

I currently have an Azure pipeline that uses a PowerShell task to run a script that performs table operations using the SAS strings to authenticate. I want to modify it to use the Azure Service Connections, is this possible? I know I have to provide the 'azureSubscription' name in the PowerShell task, but how do I authenticate and insert data into the table storage?

Answer (score 1):

> How to use the Service Connection to insert into Azure Table Storage

You can use the below script to use the service principal to insert the data into Azure table storage.

First, create an application in the portal and assign the role of the **`Storage Table Data Contributor`** to the application.

**Command:**

```
$Appid = "<Your-app-id>"
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "<your-client-secret>" -AsPlainText -Force
$tenant = "<Your-tenant-id>"
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $Appid,$PWord
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $Credential -Tenant $tenant -ServicePrincipal -Subscription "<your-subscriptionId>"

$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName <Storage accountname> -UseConnectedAccount

$tableName = "venkat901"
New-AzStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $ctx

$storageTable = Get-AzStorageTable –Name $tableName –Context $ctx

$cloudTable = $storageTable.CloudTable

$partitionKey1 = "partition1"

Add-AzTableRow `
    -table $cloudTable `
    -partitionKey $partitionKey1 `
    -rowKey ("CA") -property @{"username"="Chris";"userid"=1}
```

The above script created a table and inserted data in the Azure blob storage.

**Output:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Perform Azure Table storage operations with PowerShell | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-how-to-use-powershell)